# Sequelize cascade delete with multiple foreign keys pointing to same table?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, sql-delete, cascade

When a user gets deleted, I'd like for the user's associated `Suggestion`, `Interest`, `Friend`, and `Block` rows to also get deleted.

Associated `Suggestion` and `Interest` rows are getting deleted, but associated `Friend` and `Block` rows are not. I'm not sure why, but my guess is it's because there are two foreign keys pointing to the `User` table from the `Friend` and the `Block` tables.

Help would be appreciated. Here are the associations:

```
SuggestionModel.belongsTo(
  UserModel,
  { foreignKey: 'suggestingUserId', as: 'suggestingUser', onDelete: 'cascade' }
);

InterestModel.belongsTo(
  UserModel, { foreignKey: 'userId', as: 'user', onDelete: 'cascade' }
);

FriendModel.belongsTo(
  UserModel,
  { foreignKey: 'initiatingUserId', as: 'initiatingUser', onDelete: 'cascade' }
);

FriendModel.belongsTo(
  UserModel,
  { foreignKey: 'targetUserId', as: 'targetUser', onDelete: 'cascade' }
);

BlockModel.belongsTo(
  UserModel,
  { foreignKey: 'blockerUserId', as: 'blockerUser', onDelete: 'cascade' },
);

BlockModel.belongsTo(
  UserModel,
  { foreignKey: 'blockedUserId', as: 'blockedUser', onDelete: 'cascade' }
);

UserModel.hasMany(
  FriendModel, { foreignKey: 'initiatingUserId', as: 'initiatingMatches', onDelete: 'cascade', hooks: true }
);

UserModel.hasMany(
  FriendModel, { foreignKey: 'targetUserId', as: 'targetMatches', onDelete: 'cascade', hooks: true }
);

UserModel.hasMany(
  InterestModel, { foreignKey: 'userId', as: 'interests' }
);
```